# How can I make a query to get a ratio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT 
    sex, SUM(total) AS total
FROM
    (SELECT 
         games, sex, COUNT(sex) AS total
     FROM 
         dbo.athlete_events$
     GROUP BY 
         sex, games
     -- ORDER BY 1 
    ) a
GROUP BY 
    sex
```

[image]

How can I make a query that will give me the ratio of Male to Female? In this example, the result should be 196594/74522, i.e. 2.64.

Comment: Do you want a result of 122072 ?

Comment: I want the result 2.64

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
select
    sum(case when sex='F' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) / sum(case when sex='M' then 1.0 else 0.0 end)
from (... your subquery...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try to build on the following:

```
select Sum(Iif(sex='M',1.0,0)) / Sum(Iif(sex='M',0,1.0))
from dbo.athlete_events$
```

Note the use of `1.0` otherwise you would just get integer division.

Answer (score 0):

Using with would be beneficial for this query

```
WITH t AS
(
    --- your query in parenthesis
    SELECT 
        games, sex, COUNT(sex) AS total
    FROM 
        dbo.athlete_events$
    GROUP BY 
        sex, games
)
SELECT
    t1.sex, t1.total, t2.sex, t2.total,
    CAST(t1.total AS float) / t2.total 
AS ratio_of_Male_to_Female
FROM
    t t1
LEFT JOIN
    t t2 ON t1.games = t2.games
WHERE 
    t1.sex = 'M' AND t2.sex = 'F'
```